# CSS Two columns layout + gradient separation

Tags: css

I am trying to show a gradient vertical separation between two columns, and a bottom horizontal gradient separation between the divs.
The following code (scss) doesn't show the bottom border:

```
.col-container {
    .column-box {
        border-width: 2px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-image: linear-gradient(to right, white, #efedf4, white) 1 stretch;
        min-height: 200px;
    }
    & > div:nth-child(odd)  {
        border-width: 2px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, #efedf4) 0 90%; 
     }}
```

While the following code only shows the bottom border:

```
.col-container {
    .column-box {
        border-width: 2px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-image: linear-gradient(to right, white, #efedf4, white) 1 stretch;
        min-height: 200px;
    }}
```

Here is the code, as you will see the left div losses its bottom border: 
https://jsfiddle.net/0nsvzqxg/

Any idea how to show only the vertical separator in between the 2 divs and the bottom border on all of them?

Thanks

Comment: would you use flex(or grid) instead float, and play with border transparency or grid-gap to show a background-gradient ? https://jsfiddle.net/0weub8gc/ https://jsfiddle.net/91qnehps/ . your code does not select all the right(good ones) boxes and overwrites some of the border rules, some of your boxes have to have 2 borders, vertical and horizontal

Comment: Hi @G-Cyr, thanks for the solution, it does work, but how do you handle more rows? Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/tL9sb3g4/

Comment: if the bg gradient is not an option, you have to update the size of each slices, but the gradient will be one way or the other  unless you set it from corner to corner https://jsfiddle.net/8byLktu2/ , with the gap, you could use 2 gradients and background-size https://jsfiddle.net/0f8gc3op/ https://jsfiddle.net/zxpf0qLg/

Comment: about the slice, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-slice *When four positions are specified, they create slices measured from the top, right, bottom, and left in that order (clockwise)*

Comment: @G-Cyr Thanks very much. That solved the issue, why don't you post the answer and I vote it up!. Saved me days of research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 things to solve.

- draw the border on two sides but from the same gradient
- select the right boxes via the nth-child() selector

Since the width of the border image is quiet small, the gradient can be drawn like a diagonal. from a top corner to the opposite bottom corner and repeated once . It could be  `linear-gradient(to bottom left,   white, #efedf4, white, #efedf4, white)`.

while you need to draw one or 2 borders, you need to update the `slice` values for each borders. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-slice

> When four positions are specified, they create slices measured from the top, right, bottom, and left in that order (clockwise)

```css
div {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, red, blue, red, blue, red)1 / 2px 2px 2px 2px stretch;
  /* what would be gradient image */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom/* or top */ left/* or right*/ , blue, red, blue, red, blue);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px white;/* break border from background */
  
  /* demo purpose */
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
}




html,
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

p {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

html {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

/* end demo */
```

```html
<div>
  <p>To figure out the gradient image needed for the border, you may draw it in the background to tune it</p>
  <p> from horizontal / vertical to diagonal, it needs to be repeated at least once.</p>
</div>
```

---

Note: *shorthand values : `border-image:/* source | slice | width | outset | repeat */`*

---

About the nth-child() selector, you can use a counter CSS to see better where each child stands .

```css
.col-container {
  counter-reset: box
}

.column-box:nth-child(odd) {
  color: tomato
}

.column-box::before {
  counter-increment: box;
  content: 'child N°:'counter(box)' ';
  color: green
}
```

```html
<div class="col-container">
  <div class="column-box">
    <div class="cover">
      Image
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-box">
    <div class="cover">
      Image
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column-box">
    <div class="cover">
      Image
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column-box">
    <div class="cover">
      Image
    </div>
  </div>
```

Once put together, it can be :

```css
.col-container {
  overflow: auto;
}

.col-container > * {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-container .column-box {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;

  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, white, #efedf4, white, #efedf4, white)
    2/ 0 0 2px 0 stretch;
  min-height: 30vh;
}
.col-container > div:nth-child(odd) {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;

  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, white, #efedf4, white, #efedf4, white)
    2/0 2px 2px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-container">
  <div class="column-box">
    <div class="cover">
      Image
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-box">
    <div class="cover">
      Image
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column-box">
    <div class="cover">
      Image
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column-box">
    <div class="cover">
      Image
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column-box">
    <div class="cover">
      Image
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column-box">
    <div class="cover">
      Image
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column-box">
    <div class="cover">
      Image
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column-box">
    <div class="cover">
      Image
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Note: `flex` + `flex-wrap` would be a better option than `float`, each boxes of each rows will be the same height.